# Apache rewrite rule for converting request subdomain to destination domain?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy

I am trying to create a proxy which will basically do this -

www.google.com.myproxy.com/path?query ->  www.google.com/path?query

I am very new to Apache2 and I was able to come up with the following Rewrite rule based on what I understood from their documentation -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.localhost\.com(.*)$ $1$2 [P]
```

In this rewrite rule, if I goto www.google.com.myproxy.com I am just seeing the Apaches home page i.e. same content I see if I go to myproxy.com directly. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the correct Rewrite Rules -

```
HostnameLookups On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.myproxy\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [P]
```

Using this I am able to proxy content using -

```
www.reddit.com.myproxy.com/r/india
```

from

```
www.reddit.com/r/india
```

Thanks to following documentation -
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html